# 1987 GMC pickup - will not crank

Tags: battery, starting, gmc

I have a 87 GMC pickup. It was running fine yesterday.  Went to get in it this morning and nothing. The cab light came on at first, but now nothing. When I hook jumper cables to it I get a spark from the cables.

Does that mean the battery has power? After tried to jump it, no lights in cab and it doesn't even click when i try to crank it. I replaced the battery on April 2nd.

Comment: It sounds like your not getting a connection through the terminals on the battery. Try pulling them off and cleaning them and see if it makes a difference. It could also be the ground connection on the other end from the battery.

Comment: I cleaned the cables and that didn't change anything. Still no power.

Comment: Did the power come back on temporarily until you tried to start it, or still absolutely nothing?

Comment: No there was no temporary power.

Comment: There should be at least two + battery leads coming off of the battery. One goes to the starter solenoid. The other should go to the alternator and provide power for the rest of the vehicle. Check the secondary (smaller) lead to ensure there it is viable. You can do this through a continuity check from both ends. If there is a fusible link in it, it might have blown causing the lack of power to the truck.

Comment: Ended up having a friend come look at it and we are now up and running. If I understood right there was a loose wire and something about the in line fuse. But thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your not getting a connection through the terminals on the battery. Try pulling them off and cleaning them and see if it makes a difference. It could also be the ground connection on the other end from the battery.

There should be at least two + battery leads coming off of the battery. One goes to the starter solenoid. The other should go to the alternator and provide power for the rest of the vehicle. Check the secondary (smaller) lead to ensure there it is viable. You can do this through a continuity check from both ends. If there is a fusible link in it, it might have blown causing the lack of power to the truck.